# How to use the Jpexs Decompiler Output

Tags: flash, adobe, ffdec

We have an old Flash app on one of our websites that's essentially a full-blown application. There are about 8 screens, 'next' buttons, input fields, etc.

I used the jpexs decompiler to successfully export all the content to an FLA, but when I try to open this file in Adobe Animate and publish to HTML5, I get a ton of errors and long-running scripts that I eventually have to kill.

I see there is another option in this decompiler to "export all data.' I did this and ended up with about 10 different folders of images, actionscript files, etc. I noticed when I broswed to the startup class document in the tool, it pointed me to an Actionscript file.

Does anyone have any documentation or tips on how to use this tool to create either an FLA that can be exported to HTML5 or an HTML5 solution in itself? I have a feeling we might have to seek out the developer of this Flash app to get the raw source files, but that was like 15 yrs ago....

Ben

Comment: AS3 applications (I assume it is AS3 though AS3 was initially released in 2006) are not automatically compatible for publishing to HTML5. You will have, more or less, to completely rewrite the application to JavaScript, DOM and canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although this is not the answer I was hoping to hear :). Oh well, it should be a fun project to work on.